# Looping through data structure in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following data structure:

```
{
data: [
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'ItemOne'
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        name: 'ItemTwo'
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: 'ItemThree'
    }
]
```

}

And I want to loop through it, but I'm struggling. I've tried:

```
for result,value of results
  console.log results
  item = 0
  message = "Component: " + value[item]['name'] + " Status: " + value[item]['status']
  output.push message
  item++
```

But it only return one result. I'm obviously miles off, but what do I need to do?

Comment: The data structure you have shown is not valid, it has lot of mistakes.

Comment: Json syntax error.Write valid json.

Comment: I've updated the datastructure, I had to modify the original and didn't error check it

Comment: Also, this structure is coming from another app, I aren't creating it - just trying to parse it.

Comment: My answer below is based on the first version of this structure. I will leave it as is, as it was one of your original challenges.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through `.data`. Here is a fully working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hd4ru1kf/5/

---

*Originally in the question there was also a problem with the data notation*

You can benefit from learning the [CoffeeScript JSON notation here](http://coffeescript.org/#literals).

```
kids =
  brother:
    name: "Max"
    age:  11
  sister:
    name: "Ida"
    age:  9
```

Compiles to:

```
kids = {
  brother: {
    name: "Max",
    age: 11
  },
  sister: {
    name: "Ida",
    age: 9
  }
};
```

In your example you have `,` characters that are invalid and the whole JSON structure is way off. You have also  nested the JSON awkwardly, perhaps you don't want that? Instead I think this is the working version you are looking for (you can use http://coffeescript.org/ to check it out):

```
data:
    [
        {
            id: 1
            name: "Item one"
        }
        {
            id: 2
            name: "Item two"
        }
        {
            id: 3
            name: "Item three"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Yeah that's the right structure, thanks for pointing it out. My problem is I'm trying to loop through it and get the elements properly with the key/value notation?

Comment: Did this fix your problem? It works here (you also didn't go deep enough in your code): http://jsfiddle.net/hd4ru1kf/3/

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick, I'm missing a way to get the array key (ie 0, 1, 2)

Comment: Sampsa, the .data part is what I was missing and what I needed. Thankyou!